# DocuSign: Using the custom workflow of the DocuSign AddRecipients, cannot add same recipient

Tags: docusignapi

I add two **SAME** recipients with different routing order and role. The other is **CC(routing order = 1)** the another one is a **signer (routing order = 99)**. But whenever it never add the CC one. Do you know what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *Create Envelope* API request, try adding **allowRecipientRecursion** as a top-level property of the **Envelope** object:

```
{ 
    "allowRecipientRecursion": "true"
}
```

Setting **allowRecipientRecursion** to **true** in the *Create Envelope* API request should allow a recipient to appear more than once in the routing order.

Comment: Where can I find that? And actually, I was talking about the OOB. There's a new solution in DocuSign that has their custom workflow.

Comment: You tagged your question with the "docusignapi" tag -- are you using the API, or just using the DocuSign web console?  Can you provide a link to a webpage that describes what you mean by "DocuSign custom workflow"?