# DocuSign API multiple roles for one person

Tags: docusignapi

What format of the JSON required for one person (recipient) acting on multiple roles (or having multiple signatures)?

Until now We had one recipient acting on a single role. Now signatory/person/recipient have to fulfill multiple role and so multiple signature.

Example:

```
{
  "signHereTabs": [
    {
      "tabLabel": "PRINCIPAL_REVIEWER1_SIGNATURE1",
      "recipientId": "6"
    }
  ],
  "dateSignedTabs": [
    {
      "tabLabel": "PRINCIPAL_REVIEWER1_SIGNATURE1_eSignDateSigned",
      "recipientId": "6"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: {"signHereTabs":[{"tabLabel":"PRINCIPAL_REVIEWER1_SIGNATURE1","recipientId":"6"}],"dateSignedTabs":[{"tabLabel":"PRINCIPAL_REVIEWER1_SIGNATURE1_eSignDateSigned","recipientId":"6"}]}

Comment: Amit K Bist : Could u please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. To add more information to your question, you can EDIT your question.

Answer (score 0):

To have one person in multiple roles in an envelope, set the field `allowRecipientRecursion` to "true"

This field is at the top level of the envelope definition.

See this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122408/docusign-using-the-custom-workflow-of-the-docusign-addrecipients-cannot-add-sa/39125768#39125768).